# Hiding btrfs drives (part of raid0 array) in Gnome Nautilus?

Tags: btrfs, file-manager

I have a raid 0 array consisted of sdb to sdf devices.

My issue is that all 5 devices show up in Nautilus. I've tried other distro like deepin and I had the same issue. Mdadm and ZFS, this issue is not present.

How can I hide these btrfs ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you've got a `btrfs` file system consisting of three devices and using raid1. The file system contains one subvolume "home" which is defined in the `fstab` and mounted at `/home`, `fstab` entry looks like this:

```
/dev/sdb3   /home   btrfs   device=/dev/sdb3,device=/dev/sdc,device=/dev/sda,compress=lzo,su
```

In this example, you can hide btrf drivers by adding a `fstab` entry with a `/mnt` mount point, that would be:

```
/dev/sdc1       /mnt/nonexistent               btrfs   noauto        0       0
/dev/sdb1       /mnt/nonexistent               btrfs   noauto        0       0
```

Nautilus will only show those sidebar entries if your mount point is under `/media`. Using a mount point under `/mnt` should make Nautilus ignore the filesystem.